# problem in making HLS using ffmpeg problem

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a function do run in background and create m3u8 for some videos: (I is running in background and updating some fields in django).

```
def convert_to_hls(episode):
    # Set the output directory for HLS files
output_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'hls')
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Set the input video file path
input_file_path = episode.videoFile.path

# Set the output filename and path for the HLS playlist
# filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_file_path))[0]
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
filename = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(45))
playlist_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{filename}.m3u8')

# Set the output path for the HLS segments
segments_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{filename}_%05d.ts')

# Construct the ffmpeg command for HLS conversion
command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', input_file_path,
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-crf', '23',
    '-preset', 'medium',
    '-c:a', 'aac',
    '-b:a', '128k',
    '-f', 'hls',
    '-hls_time', '10',
    '-hls_list_size', '0',
    '-hls_segment_filename', segments_path,
    playlist_path
]
# Execute the ffmpeg command
subprocess.run(command, check=True)

episode.hls_created = True
episode.hls_url = playlist_path.replace("/home/debian/project","")
episode.save()

return True
```

this code works well for most of my videos but for some **.mp4** files gets:

```
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.511095 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504] Exception in thread Thread-1:
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.511198 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.511244 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.512078 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]     self.run()
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.512124 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.512707 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.512748 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]   File "/home/debian/project/twapp/views/episode_backgrounds.py", line 41, in convert_to_hls
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.512950 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]     subprocess.run(command, check=True)
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.512989 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.513500 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504]     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
[Fri Jun 23 17:05:47.513657 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 19975:tid 140289048565504] subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-i', '/home/debian/project/media/videos/introduction_to_raster_qBhrnAx.mp4', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-crf', '23', '-preset', 'medium', '-c:a', 'aac', '-b:a', '128k', '-f', 'hls', '-hls_time', '10', '-hls_list_size', '0', '-hls_segment_filename', '/home/debian/project/media/hls/ZN3fsJVEfTDEc8MFb5DrP7Y34JFNLj0hfWnGRZAwFdjuG_%05d.ts', '/home/debian/project/media/hls/ZN3fsJVEfTDEc8MFb5DrP7Y34JFNLj0hfWnGRZAwFdjuG.m3u8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Also it does not work for **.MOV** files.